# Why does WWW::Mechanize fail with "X-Died: Illegal field name 'X-Meta-Twitter:title'"?

Tags: perl, curl, www-mechanize

Why does `WWW::Mechanize` have blank content after getting the following URL?  Using a browser or `curl` there is a full HTML page retrieved.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
$mech->get("http://www.belizejudiciary.org/web/judgements2/");
print $mech->content  # prints nothing
```

Here is the dump of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 00:51:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Client-Aborted: die
Client-Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 00:51:48 GMT
Client-Peer: 98.129.229.64:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Link: <http://www.belizejudiciary.org/web/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://www.belizejudiciary.org/web/?p=468>; rel=shortlink
Set-Cookie: X-Mapping-hepadkon=FAB86566672CEB74D66B2818CA030616; path=/
X-Died: Illegal field name 'X-Meta-Twitter:title' at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/sun4-solaris/HTML/HeadParser.pm line 207.
X-Pingback: http://www.belizejudiciary.org/web/xmlrpc.php
```

I have version 3.70 of HTML::Parser installed.

Comment: I'm not getting nothing. What version of the module do you use? What is the contents of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($mech->response)`?

Comment: @choroba My system has version 3.70 of `HTML:Parser`, so that might be a problem.  See my edit for the response.

Comment: @choroba adding `$mech->parse_head(0)` before the `get` solved the problem. From this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17745491/327528

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of [that other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14740365) you found, but those answers both leave something to be desired. I mean, monkey-patching HTML::HeadParser? Disabling header parsing altogether? Really?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot In my opinion that is the problem in marking questions as duplicates.

Comment: It might be better to mark that question as a dup of this one. Your question is better since it includes the actual error.

Answer (score 2):

Your dump shows that there was an error parsing the response:

> X-Died: Illegal field name 'X-Meta-Twitter:title' at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/sun4-solaris/HTML/HeadParser.pm line 207.

This is caused by a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=80524) in HTML::HeadParser:

> `<meta>` tags can have name attributes with colons in them, and this is perfectly valid. But HTML::HeadParser then tries to register these as `X-Meta-<name>` headers using HTTP::Headers. Newer versions of HTTP::Headers (since 6.05) have stricter checks for headers, and will refuse them if they contain colons.

This was fixed in version 3.71 of the HTML-Parser distribution, so you should upgrade.